# To use sony tv with HDMI port as Toshiba laptop screen

Tags: toshiba-laptop

I want to use my tv screen as laptop display. My laptop is bit old, Toshiba satellite c640 with 2 usb ports, one vga, 2 audio jacks (one for earphone and another for microphone), and one network adapter.  My tv is sony with usb ports and one HDMI port.

Can I use any of these to connect my laptop to tv screen?  I want to use my tv screen as laptop display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a VGA to HDMI adapter like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006FILNV6).

There are USB to HDMI [adapters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01KJS1W1I), however with a slow USB port, the video will not be very fast.  Games, movies, etc will stutter a lot.

Comment: But my tv showing HDMI female port,So how can i connect that with, the HDMI adapter given in link?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of the TV and the quality of the adapter,  you may find VGA to HDMI conversion provides inadequate quality.

You may be able to find inexpensive laptops with broken screens (and a HDMI port) that would be worth upgrading to instead of converting the signal.